# Send images in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to convert a base64 image into a physical file in ionic, does anyone know how to do it?

```
takePhoto(sType: number) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      correctOrientation: true,
      sourceType: sType,
    } 
    console.log(options)
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.fotoUsuario = this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData)
      console.log('hola',this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData))
      this.EditarFoto()
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('Error')
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic tutorial is clear. https://ionicframework.com/blog/storing-photos-with-the-cordova-camera-and-file-plugins/

also look at: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/saving-photos  for capacitor project.

this tutorial is for cordova plugin, install file plugin too.

```
# File plugin
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file

 
takePhoto(sType: number) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    }
    
    // get filesystem
    const tempImage = await this.camera.getPicture(options);

    // extract just file name, this ex for iOS, android will look familiar
    const tempFilename = tempImage.substr(tempImage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    // extract full path , except file name
    const tempBaseFilesystemPath = tempImage.substr(0, tempImage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    
    // get Data Directory of device
    const newBaseFilesystemPath = this.file.dataDirectory;
    
    // copy file from temp stroage to permanent file storage
    await this.file.copyFile(tempBaseFilesystemPath, tempFilename, 
                             newBaseFilesystemPath, tempFilename);
    
    // your stored file
    const storedPhoto = newBaseFilesystemPath + tempFilename;

    // display image
    this.fotoUsuario = this.webview.convertFileSrc(storedPhoto);
    console.log('hola',this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData))
}
```